# mininet-wifi/examples/handover.py throws error

Tags: python, networking, mininet, openflow, sdn

installed from https://github.com/intrig-unicamp/mininet-wifi .

executing mininet/examples/handover.py throws error:

File "./handover.py", line 55, in

```
topology()
```

File "./handover.py", line 20, in topology

sta1 = net.addStation( 'sta1', mac='00:00:00:00:00:02', ip='10.0.0.2/8' )

AttributeError: 'Mininet' object has no attribute 'addStation'

sudo mn --wifi --ssid=new_ssid also shows error:

```
Usage: mn [options]
```

(type mn -h for details)

mn: error: no such option: --wifi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably Mininet-WiFi is not installed in your machine. Please, check if you are using Mininet instead of Mininet-WiFi. The current version of Mininet-WiFi is 1.6r5.